# PDF reporting using Microsoft reporting services (.rdlc)

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting-services

Is there anyway to create Table of Contents for pdf generating using rdlc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [document map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159774%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to your report. When you export to PDF, the document map elements are shown a table of contents entries.